# python apschedule BlockingScheduler with interval trigger: Start immediately

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using python apscheduler to schedule a specific task every 45 minutes. The problem is, when i add the job and start the scheduler, it starts at 45 minutes from now.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

class myClass:

    def schedule(self):
        self.scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
        self.scheduler.add_job(self.myJob, 'interval', minutes=45)
        self.scheduler.start()

    def myJob(self):
        print('I finally started')
```

I tried setting start_date, but with no success. How can i make sure the job is executed immediately, and not after waiting the interval for the first time?

Comment: The design of the interval trigger has been fixed in the upcoming v4.0 release so that the first run starts immediately.

Comment: ahh! long overdue ty. Not realeased yet though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try `next_run_time=datetime.now()`.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`, then I use `datetime.utcnow()` because I set up my scheduler with `BlockingScheduler({'apscheduler.timezone': 'UTC'})`

Answer (score 6):

Not a good solution but works for me.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

class myClass:

    def schedule(self):
        self.myJob()#run your job immediately here, then scheduler
        self.scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
        self.scheduler.add_job(self.myJob, 'interval', minutes=45)
        self.scheduler.start()

    def myJob(self):
        print('I finally started')
```

Answer (score 1):

The given answers are too complex for a simple task that is well documented:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/date.html#examples

**To add a job to be run immediately:**

The 'date' trigger and datetime.now() as run_date are implicit

```
sched.add_job(my_job)
```